NextCloud failed to find MariaDB
I am following the site (https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-install-nextcloud-openmediavault-nas/) to setup Nextcloud on OMV. Everything looks fine until the last step that is to create admin user account for Nextcloud.
In the nextcloud setup page, for database host, I have tried localhost, mariadb, mariadb-db-1 but none seems to work.
Error for using hostname as localhost
Error while trying to create admin account: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Error for using mariadb / mariadb-db-1
Error while trying to create admin account: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: Try again

My guess is MariaDB is setup in network mariadb_default while NextCloud is in host so nextcloud cant found the db in localhost? What I should use for the database host? I should have change the config in the portainer somewhere?
Script to I used to setup the MariaDB
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5 
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW 
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/Nextcloud_Database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcabc 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextclouddb
      - MYSQL_USER=nextclouduser

Container and network setup are as follow


